# laravel5.1 jobs not working in background

Tags: php, laravel-5, queue

I have used laravel 5.1 with jenssegers integration.
I have created one job which creates CSV file.
I have followed steps to execute this job into background -

```
1) Got request parameters in Controller.
2) Process data and stored it into jobs table.
3) Using DispatchesJobs trait called this job by passing jobId

$this->dispatch((new ExportJobs($id))->delay(6000));

4) Return jobId for HTTP request.

Note: my CSV file data is too small so it don't take more time to     create
so I have added sleep(120); into that job class.

5) hit PHP artisan queue:listen into terminal
```

But still, the execution waited for 120 seconds and then my controller return jobId as a response.

My question is how can I process this job in a background?

Comment: anyone can help me here?